# Exporting database using mysql command line

Tags: mariadb, export

I am using mysql to export a database from my application, the options I have so far:

```
--skip-comments
--compact
--lock-tables=false
--add-drop-database
--host=localhost
--user=trainer
--password=XXXX
--routines
--databases
training
```

The above are from a String list (a collection of strings, in this case a Qt QStringList. (C++).).  The executable is **mariadb-dump.exe**

When the file is generated using the above I see in the file:

```
CRLF
/*!40000 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `training`*/;CRLF
```

There are several lines that have comments in them like this, does this mean the above will not be executed?  If Yes, how to I fix this in the export so these lines are not commented out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [conditional syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/).

```
/*!XXXXXX .... */
```

means that statement will be executed if current mariadb version is equal to or higher than `XXXXXX`. In your case database `training` will be dropped if server you have dump loaded to is of version 4.0 or higher.